# How to set a value in a Choice Field based on the text box change SP 2010 in list newform.aspx

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, jquery, sputility

I am having few  fields like `single line of text`, `choice field`, `rich text` on my `customnewform.aspx` of my SP 2010 `SPList`.
Now if I enter a value say **USA** on the text box, I need to set the dropdown/choice field value as **Boeing** if I enter the text box value as **Europe** then the choice field value must be set to **Airbus**.
 The choice  field contains many values,like company1, company2, company3, company4 along with Boeing, Airbus etc 
How this can be achieved using SPutility & jQuery & JavaScript ? 
Am trying to use  onblur function of my textbox.  Will this work ?
Also I need to get the validation done within the PreSaveAction function call also.

```
 <script language="javascript" src="/project/EASAssetsLib/jquery-
       1.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
     </script><script language="javascript" 
    src="/project/EASAssetsLib/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" 
    src="/project/EASAssetsLib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script><script language="javascript" 
    src="/project/EASAssetsLib/SPUtility.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
    {
   var txtboxfromSPUTIL = SPUtility.GetSPField('countryname').GetValue(); 
   alert(txtboxfromSPUTIL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Break up your Mission in smaller tasks, you allready started with alert()

Ditch alert and learn to use F12 Developer Tools

In Chrome you can use Snippets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support

That will execute any of your javascript on the current page and saves you from loading it in SharePoint

As for your tasks

- Attach a JavaScript event handler, `onblur` is fine, maybe you want `keyup` for a better UX
- Check what people typed
- Set the values of the Choice field

Plenty of examples around, *see the column on the right of this page for related questions & answers*

Success with you Mission

Comment: I am little bit confused with this jQuery and its use in content Editor web part, like how to write this jQuery functions and  where should I write. In JavaScript,we can create multiple functions and call from other functions.But here, am not sure how to call the onblur, on keyup etc etc.Sorry for telling this silly things.

Comment: Then learn SharePoint+jQuery first: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/82b15a/client-side-programming-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/ You can't fly a plane without learning to fly

Comment: Thanks for the url for starting with CSOM.Purposefully avoided this jQuery+JavaScript CSOM, because of my favourism towards writing SSOM code and FullTrust solutions.Now am forced to learn & write these client side stuff. I don't have any other option now!

Comment: Your requirement of changing a DropDown has got nothing to do with JSOM/CSOM.. its just plain HTML/Javascript